# GAE/J This application does not exist (app_id=u'app-id')

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm having this problem that I can't deploy to GAE cloud. I am using the [appcfg.sh script](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/appcfg).

I have already did this:

```
./appcfg.sh update "/path/to/war" --no_cookies
```

And still getting the error. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you create the application with this id in http://appengine.google.com ?

Comment: Yes, I did, I can view its dashboard, etc.

Comment: I have seen this failing intermittently a few weeks ago for one of my GAE/J apps. To work around this, I created a new app ID and temporarily deployed to it. The next day it started working again and I removed the temporary app ID. It's generally a good idea to let your clients talk to a custom domain and then use DNS to point this custom domain to a specific app ID. This allows you to change the app ID or even move from GAE to EC2 without clients noticing.

Comment: Please ensure that appcfg.py is using the correct credentials. If you have used appcfg.py with another account it may have remembered the details.